# PlayOnLinux windows/dialogs display incorrectly in elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, playonlinux

I installed PlayOnLinux 4.2.12 from the AppCenter on elementary OS 5 Juno.  Each window/dialog of POL displays twice with one window inside the other.  When I bring up the install dialog.  The inner window for that window does not display all the controls on the window, and makes it unusable.  I have need to run a windows app that is needed for work.

I have run Luna since 2013 and POL works great with Luna (And thus I have been able to install and use the needed application).  I am unable at this time to do the same in Juno.

Any help on how to get PlayOnLinux to display correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems this double window/dialog happens for a high percentage of applications.  This happens with Ecllipse too.  It would be good to see this fixed.

Comment: Have the same issue. They told us its gonna be a milestone for Elementary OS. I was happy with 0.4.1 but version 5 is disappointment. Please help

Comment: As it turns out, not only eOS users, but also people from other distros experience this problem as well. https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-16067-PlayOnLinux_windowsdialogs_display_incorrectly_on_Elementary_OS_Juno.html

Comment: Has there been a fix released for this?

Comment: Found the issue diving through the links above and summarized it :
[reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/evob06/how_to_fix_softwares_with_double_window_frame](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/evob06/how_to_fix_softwares_with_double_window_frame/) Thanks @Cassidy James Blaede

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with a small number of apps that explicitly request window decorations, and is being tracked at https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244

Answer (score 2):

you can launch playonlinux into a terminal with :

```
Exex=env GTK_CSD=0 /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux
```

or

you can change PlayOnLinux.desktop file : */usr/share/applications/PlayOnLinux.desktop*

```
Exec=playonlinux %F
```

by

```
Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 playonlinux %F
```

If you don't know where is *.desktop file, use Menu Editor to find it and change it.